# formdata object is empty for html form post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, form-data

I'm trying to use formdata object to send form data to my server. I need this because one of my input fields is a file. However the formdata object is blank when I try to send the data to my server, it also prints out "{}". What is the issue? I have jquery updated to 11.1 which supports formdata. Thanks.

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formName" id="formId">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
  </form>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl sub">Send Message</button>

  <script>
      $(".sub").click(function(){
         var formElement = document.querySelector("form");
         alert(formElement); //alert message is "[object HTMLFormElement]"
         var d = new FormData(formElement);
         alert(JSON.stringify(d)); //alert message is "{}"
         $.post("/email",d,function(data){
            alert("success!");
         });
      });
  </script>
```

Server:

```
/*never reaches endpoint*/
app.post('/email', function(req, res) {
    console.log("entered");
    console.log(req.body) // form fields
    console.log(req.files) // form files
    var resume = req.files;
    email(req.body, resume);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: it's an empty object, that's what it looks like as a string. aside: it will look the same to JSON.stringify() even if populated...

Comment: I'm wondering why it's an empty object. I'm not able to send the populated form with my post request. Its empty on client and it never makes it to server. Does anything look off about my request?

Comment: ok, well what is `$.post`  ?

Comment: a [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) post request that is supposed to send form data to my server. I was able to successfully communicate client/server with my code before I tried implementing the FormData object... so I'm thinking its probably the cause but I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

How are you parsing the body of POST requests on your node server?

The issue is that `FormData` will set the content type to be `multipart/form-data`, which Express' `body-parser` doesn't understand.

Note the comment [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser):

> [body-parser] does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules: busboy and connect-busboy; multiparty and connect-multiparty; formidable; multer.

So in other words, you have to user a different module to handle the multipart body that FormData sends. I can recommend `formidable`, in which case you're server code would look something like:

```
const formidable = require('formidable')

exports.createPost = (req, res, next) => {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        console.log(fields)
        res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: pollsController createPost');
    }
}
```